# Hyperledger Fabric - First Network Sample - Error while creating the channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, channel, creation

Hyperledger Fabric: I am using the fabric samples.

While running the command

```
./byfn.sh -m up
```

I am getting the following error while creating the channel:

> 018-02-27 19:34:51.325 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey ->
>   ERRO 001 Failed loading private key  [ec1f4a4699b91d9e6010e30aea31c0d1ba60f4e1787b84a5e03bb7aafc730b5a]: [open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/ec1f4a4699b91d9e6010e30aea31c0d1ba60f4e1787b84a5e03bb7aafc730b5a_sk: permission denied].
>   2018-02-27 19:34:51.325 UTC [main] main ->
>   ERRO 002 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp:
>   KeyMaterial not found in SigningIdentityInfo
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

What can be the reason for this error message and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the Correct path of **Go** in environment variable.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y golang-go make
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
make docker
```